# Remove all links from DOM html with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

There is a string `$processhtml` containing some html. I am trying to remove all link tags along with its contents from html with help of PHP.

To illustrate:

```
"This is some text with <a href="#">link</a>"
```

has to become:

```
"This is some text with"
```

I do some other parsing on that html with help of DOMDocument, so trying to find a solution related to DOM.

I've tried:

```
           $dom = new DOMDocument();
           @$dom->loadHtml($processhtml);
            foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
                if ($element->nodeName == 'a') {
                    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
                }
            }
            echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The results:

1. Some of the links removed completely (Good)
2. Some of the links replaced with "Question mark" characters (Wierd)
3. Some of the links left unchanged (Not Good)

[image]

So my questions are:

1) What causes such inconsistency in the code I use and how to resolve it?

2)Is there a better way to achieve the desired functionality? (regex is a no-no ;P )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, question marks come from encoding issue, make sure you declare the right encoding.
If you want 100% efficiency I would rather use preg_replace() matching all elements starting with "<a" and ending with ">", and replacing them by an empty string. Then make another replacement as follow : str_replace ('</a>', '', $my_string);

Comment: @VincentTeyssier What about the content between `<a ...>` and `</a>`? It has to be removed as well

Comment: Than you make a global preg_replace() catching all strings starting by "<a" and ending by "</a>". That will replace the whole block.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier: 100% efficient? by using regexes to mangle html? That's just... dumb. dom is **THE** specific tool for the proper manipulation of html/xml. just because regexes (aka hammer) can be used to do something, doesn't mean you're going to use that hammer to polish your collection of delicate crystal.

Comment: make sure you're preserving the charset of the html. e.g. if the input html is utf8, and your output environment from your script is iso8859, you WILL get corrupted characters. plus, compare the input html against the output html. DOM is very picky about its inputs and can/will barf on the simplest of html malformations.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier I've tried that before but there were some inconsistencies as well, and I afraid some bad html formatting could messed it as well. By turning to DOM I was hoping to get the most reliable way to do it

Comment: Did you inspect the source code of the page to see if there's anything there that shouldn't be? DOMDocument may be outputting more than it's needed, you may have to mess with the options for it, or do some post filtering on the output of saveHTML(). http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: Well you might not like it, but html is text and regex are made for that. Regex will not miss a single block, therefore yes it is 100% efficient. But I'm open to any opinion showing that it won't catch 100% of the desired regex.

Comment: @acidon show me the regex you used for your tries pls. If there is any bad html formating, then DOM will fail also. The only bad formating would be a missing close tag </a>, which would anyway make the whole page inconsistent.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier I know next to nothing about creating correct regex expressions so I had to google yesterday to find a regex solution, but could only find the ones that didn't work on all of the links. Then I googled and came across many post encouraging to use DOM instead of regex for better reliability. Now I tried to find one at your request but instead came across the one that actually catched all the links on the page - `/<a .*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+)[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/ig`. So far it is more reliable then a DOM method I use. If there is no way to fine-tune "picky" DOM, Ill go with regex :)

Comment: Ok, try by reducing your regex like this one : /<a .*?<\/a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/<a .*?<\/a>';
preg_replace($pattern, "", $processhtml);
```

Tested and working on https://regex101.com/

Comment: I've got "Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition" gathering dust on a bookshelf, maybe its time to start getting into that 500+ pages monster :) Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: Regex are a nightmare, but working so well.... regex101.com is detailing quite well the regex you can find on SO so you can adapt them without extensive knowledge.... enjoy :)